# SHA1 encode data and access hash result in a grails view

Tags: grails

This is in the view

```
<g:passwordField name="password" required="" value="${usuarioInstance?.password}"/>
```

This would be a part of the controller

```
pass = params.password.encodeAsSHA1()
```

This will be returned into the view again
    ${pass.password}

the ${pass.password} needs to change to text or decode the SHA1()

Comment: SHA-1 is no longer considered secure

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @stark It isn't SHA-1, it is that any cryptographic hash by itself is insufficient for securing a password. Further SHA-1 is only broken for signing. SHA-1 is as valid for passwords as SHA-512 and neither are secure for passwords.

Answer (score 4):

My advice:

1. don't use sha-1, it's insecure
2. don't unencrypt a password and display it in a form field. Make the user type it in if they want to change it, if they haven't entered anything then don't update that property
3. use spring security which by default manages all the headaches of web security and uses Bcrypt out of the box.

Security is something every dev needs to take seriously and if the client insists on unsecure practices then they need to be educated.

Edit: @zaph makes a good point below so I should add it - don't encrypt passwords.  A password should never be able to be translated back into plain text.  Always hash (and salt) them and compare the user input hash to the stored hash.  If you choose not to use Spring Security, you can use Bcrypt standalone and use the static `Bcrypt.checkpw(userInputPw, hashedPw)` method to check it.

Final Edit:  To avoid any confusion (since @zaph seems confused in the comments) my recommendation is to use Bcrypt - specifically, use Spring Security.

Comment: I regret that I have only one upvote for this answer

Comment: 1. Should be: *Don't use any cryptographic hash*. SHA-512 essentially provides no more security for a password than SHA-1, neither are secure for passwords. 2. Should be: *Don't encrypt passwords".

Comment: @yachayx No it is essentially random, that is it can not be distunguished from random bytes. Just use correct password security.

Comment: @yachayx SHA-1, indeed all cryptographic functions are designed to be one-way, that is not reversible, and as part of the hash process some information is discarded. For passwords to be secure they need to be irreversible and more, see my comment to the question. The point is to protect the client.

Comment: @Todd Sharp Still you are suggest using a hash function, that is not secure. A one-way function that takes substantial CPU time, generally in the range of 100ms, is required, hash functions are in the range of 1us for passwords. Additionally there needs to be a random element such as a salt so that two identical passwords don't have the same representation. `Bcrypt` meets these requirements and is acceptable and secure, hash functions are not. See my comment to the question for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying...Bcrypt *is* a hash, but you're saying a hash function is not secure?  You literally can't use Bcrypt *without* a salt, so, I'm suggesting using Bcrypt which meets what I interpret your comment to say...

Comment: I realize you don't understand, that is a large part of the problem. 1. `Bcrypt` is much more than a hash, it has a random salt and an iteration count, it is designed to use considerable CPU time. 2. You state "Always hash (and salt)" but that is not sufficient, adding a salt does little to improve security, the function must be CPU intensive requiring around 100ms to compute. 3. Just stating sha-1 is insecure is disingenuous in that there is an implication other hashes such as SHA-256 are a solution when none are secure on their own. 4. It's the users are at risk from poor password handling.

Comment: Here is a slide presentation: [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton, in particular see slide 23.

Comment: Alright, you're just being pedantic now.  You know what I mean and you know that I know what I'm talking about.  Thanks for proving that you're smarter than me though.

Comment: No and no. Re: pedantic; yes security is pedantic. If secure practices are not used the users are put at risk, if insecure rules are provided that works against the users. It is not about smart, it is about providing information that will help developers create secure code, in this case password security for the sake of the users. It would be great if the answer was updated to current practices, then we could delete this whole comment exchange and I could upvote a good answer. Why not?

Comment: @zaph - Good lord. Todd Sharp's initial response met your requirements: he said "Bcrypt out of the box." Your responses are continually expanding the scope of the (well answered) original question. Sure, Todd could go on explaining about what kind of hash to use, how much CPU time it should use, and eventually down to the point of how much wattage the underlying machine's underlying power supply should draw, but that's going well beyond what the original asker need to know. It seems like you care more about showing off your knowledge than helping answer the original question.

Comment: @zaph or, you could provide what you consider to be a 'good answer'.

Comment: Todd states hashing with salt ("hash (and salt) ") is an accedptable method, it is not, it is not secure…at all. See my comment to the question and I have provided a link to a presentation. I care about the users security.

Comment: That's where the pedant comment comes in.  You're beating a dead horse here - Bcrypt, behind the scenes, does all that stuff you're talking about.  Does it matter to the OP how it does what it does?  Or does it just matter that's it's the industry standard for doing it right now.  Use Bcrypt.  That's the answer.  We all care about the user's security - that's why we use Spring Security which uses Bcrypt.

Comment: I stated that Bcrypt is a good and acceptable solution. It seems the issue is about not making the answer accurate for some reason, that insecure suggestions are OK. Yes, current industry standards do matter. Example: a password hash with SHA-512 takes about 1us, that allows running through a list of [frequent passwords](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords) very fast and effective. Increasing to 100ms is a substantial change. Thus the industry standard is 100,000 times more secure, that is substantial. Yet you state that simple hashing with a salt is a solution.

Comment: It's like you're speaking a different language than me. Is English not your first language (honest question)?  That might explain the disconnect here. Bcrypt is a hashing function. Do you disagree with that? When you use Bcrypt you're hashing a string.  `BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt());`

Comment: @ToddSharp The language I am speaking is security and cryptography, I have only been speaking English for 60+ years. Bcrypt is not a hashing function, it is much more. Saying it is a hash function is like saying HMAC or PBKDF2 are hash functions, they are not, they do more, they do *contain* hash functions. Bcrypt is closer to a derivation or key extension function such as PBKDF2.

Comment: Then I suggest you tell it's authors and update Wikipedia while you're at it. The first six words of the Wikipedia entry are: "bcrypt is a password hashing function" [Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)

Comment: In the Wikipedia quote: "bcrypt is a password hashing function" note the qualification "**password** hashing".  When a cryptographic hash function is needed bcrypt is not considered. When a slow password derivation function is required bcrypt among others such as the [NIST recommended](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf) PBKDF2 are required. Hash functions need to be fast, bcrypt is purposely slow, they have different purposes

Comment: Stating: "Always hash (and salt)" for password storage is wrong and refusing to correct that is at the expense of users who will have their security compromised To suggest against [NIST recomendations](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-132.pdf) is wrong, how vain is that!